# Using ConfigurationManager in web apps

Tags: .net, web-config, app-config, configurationmanager

As far as I understand, I should use `System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager` to read app settings in desktop applications, and `System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager` to do the same thing in web applications. This is what MSDN says.

I am developing a component that will be deployed to both desktops and web servers, so I am trying to make configuration logic independent of the platform. To my surprise, I discovered by accident that app settings are read correctly by using `System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager` on a web server.

I have two related questions:

1. Can anyone confirm that this works systematically?
2. What are the limitations or risks of using `System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager` on web applications?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[MSDN says](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.configuration.webconfigurationmanager.aspx) that `WebConfigurationManager` is the preferred way to work with configuration files in web applications.

In web applications, configuration can be inherited from a web.config file in a parent virtual directory: `WebConfigurationManager` will handle such inherited settings properly, which I believe isn't the case for `ConfigurationManager`.

Of course, if your application does not inherit such settings (e.g. is always at the root of a web site), this is not relevant to you.

Answer (score 1):

The `System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings` and `System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings` internally uses the same `System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager` - so there is no difference.

MSDN says:

> These methods perform read-only operations, use a single cached instance of the configuration, and are multithread aware.

The other methods of the `System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager` are related to configuration of ASP.NET. I consider the `System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager` as extension of `ConfigurationManager`, or even adaptation for the web ecosystem.

So, you should use the generic `System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager`.

Comment: This is not quite right. See https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#system.web/Configuration/WebConfigurationManager.cs,31 and https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#system.web/Configuration/HttpConfigurationSystem.cs,cfa741a40037db08